# How exactly did Apocalypse enhance Magneto's skills (if at all)?

Tags: plot-explanation, x-men-cinematic-universe, x-men-apocalypse

In X-Men Apocalypse, En Sabah Nur scouts four mutants to be the Horsemen of the Apocalypse.

When he first meets Storm he enhances her skills and **the change is clear** you can see her hair change color and her powers change from just small dust clouds to large storms, mist, lightning etc.

Then he meets Psylocke who at first has a small energy sword until En Sabah Nur enhances it making it longer and seemingly sharper/deadlier.

Through Psylocke he finds Arch-Angel/Angel of Death who is injured and seemingly weak. He goes through the biggest change as his wings become not only healed but enhanced to be metal which can be used as a projectile.

However when he meets Erik you **can't clearly** see his powers being enhanced. We saw Erik move entire football stadiums before X-Men Apocalypse, therefore this was just a demonstration of his powers because all he did was destroy a few buildings, which again he has done before.

My question is, what changes happened to Magneto's powers (how is it enhanced when we don't really see much changes)?

However if it wasn't enhanced, why wasn't it?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

It's really clear that Magneto's powers are **extremly** enhanced.

Let's compare his newly enhanced powers to his old ones:

#### X-Men: First Class:

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X-Men:_First_Class):

In the middle of the movie:

> ... and [Erik] Lehnsherr uses his magnetic power to lift Shaw's submarine from the water and deposit it on land.

At the end:

> Fearing the mutants, both fleets fire missiles at them, which [Erik] Lehnsherr turns back in mid-flight.

So he can lift a submarine and control some missiles in the air.

#### X-Men: Days of Future Past

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X-Men:_Days_of_Future_Past):

> Magneto appears, controlling the Sentinels, and uses the Robert F. Kennedy Memorial Stadium to surround the White House.

Surely has evolved a little bit but still...

#### X-Men: Apocalypse:

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X-Men:_Apocalypse):

> At En Sabah Nur's behest, Erik uses his powers to control the Earth's magnetic poles, causing destruction across the planet.

Now that's **enhancing**. His new powers can't be compared to anything we've seen him doing before. He is no longer just controlling his surroundings, he is controling the whole world's magnetic fields (as explained by the Pentagon scientist).

In the scene from the video above, he is controlling every single magnetic metal in the whole world at once (sunken ships, metal containers from who knows where, bridges, raw metals from deep within Earth, ... you name it). That's something he surely couldn't have done before (remember how he was struggling to lift that one submarine in the first movie).

Answer (score 13):

Although the other answer did a good job in demonstrating the enhancement, **Bryan Singer confirmed** [in an interview](http://www.ew.com/article/2015/12/29/x-men-apocalypse-magneto/) that **Magneto's powers were enhanced** by Apocalypse...

> **EW December 29, 2015**
>
> "One of Apocalypse's many powers is he can imbue other mutants with
>   greater ones," director Bryan Singer told EW. "Magneto is
>   demonstrating a small taste of what he can do now. Magneto is already
>   enormously powerful…. Now Apocalypse gives him powers far beyond what
>   we've seen before."

Comment: That interview doesn't really elaborate on "how exactly" he enhanced them, though.

Comment: No, but the question relies on the supposition that there may not be an enhancement. That's why I said that the other answer does a good job at showing the enhancment, then aknowledging that my answer does not. My answer was just addressing the FACT that he was enhanced, as Q also stated, "However if it wasn't enhanced, why wasn't it?"

Answer (score 0):

Apocalypse did enhance him when he put his hand and was telling magneto to reach as far as he could when he was touching the ground through that he enhanced him in that way. But I get what you mean hopefully that answers your question.